# How to make attributed text bold in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two `NSAttributedString`, where I am trying to make first one in bold.. I am trying to make it bold but it is not working.

```
var attrTitle : NSAttributedString
var attrBody : NSAttributedString


let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    
let boldAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attributedString:attrTitle)
let regularAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attributedString:attrBody)
mutableAttributedString.append(boldAttributedString)
mutableAttributedString.append(regularAttributedString)
```

is there any way to make it bold..Thanks for help

Comment: If's supposed to work if the value of the `.font` attribute of `attrTitle` is a bold font style.

Comment: Strings are attributed strings

Comment: Then it should work. Attributes are preserved when strings are being concatenated. And it's redundant to create an attributed string from an attributes string.

Comment: attrTitle.font is not getting

Comment: Of course not, it's part of the attributes dictionary.

Comment: can you please help with the code..

Comment: Your question is unclear. If `attrTitle` is already bold just put the strings together without creating new ones. If not use the suggestion in Maxim's answer.

Comment: attrTitle its not bold..i want to make it bold

Answer (score 0):

Seems you missed bold attributes for title string, you can achieve it via `NSAttributedString.Key.font` with any bold font value.

```
let attrTitle = "Title"
let attrBody  = "Body"

let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)]
let boldAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: attrTitle, attributes: attributes)
let regularAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attributedString: attrBody)

mutableAttributedString.append(boldAttributedString)
mutableAttributedString.append(regularAttributedString)
```

Comment: Thanks but my strings are attributed string..is there any way with that?

Comment: You can init your `attrTitle` also with attributes and pass a value for `.font` key.

Answer (score 0):

You can add attribute like this

```
   let boldAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attrTitle)
        
    boldAttributedString.addAttributes([.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)], range: NSMakeRange(0, boldAttributedString.length))
```

Comment: giving error as "Value of type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'addAttributes'"

Comment: @user7423463 Read the answer again. Did you use `NSAttributedString` instead of `NSMutableAttributedString`?

Comment: yes @Sweeper is right ... use `NSMutableAttributedString`

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to make it bold and still use *NSAttributedString*.

You have to assign the properties before hand.

```
var attrTitle : NSAttributedString
var attrBody : NSAttributedString

var mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        
//Properties
let boldFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: //your size)
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: boldFont]
       
        
let boldAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: attrTitle.string, attributes: attributes)
let regularAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attributedString:attrBody)
mutableAttributedString.append(boldAttributedString)
mutableAttributedString.append(regularAttributedString)
```

Also remember that if you want to display the attributed string you need to call *.attributedText* property of your object before assignment.

Hope this helps.